# Syntax highlighting breaks with rust analyzer

Tags: neovim, syntax-highlighting, highlight

I have been using neovim for several months with basically no issue and
enjoying it very much.  I have recently started receiving a problem with
the syntax highlighting in Rust.

When the file first loads, it uses the syntax defined in the
`$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/rust.vim` file from
[`rust.vim`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust.vim), which is what I want, but after a
few seconds (probably once rust-analyzer loads and runs), it changes
the highlighting to use different colours (there's probably a better way
to describe it, but [a video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4g12Z.jpg) is easier to show).  This colour change also
happens when I write the file (and rust-analyzer runs again).

The problem only happens in Rust, and I'm 99% sure that it's due to
rust-analyzer and its semantic highlighting.  I believe it's
rust-analyzer because when remove it from my `init.vim`, the
problem does not persist.

I've spent quite a bit of time attempting to find a solution to this
problem, but I've found nothing.

What I've tried thus far:

- Upgrading rust-analyzer
- Downgrading rust-analyzer
- Upgrading neovim
- Downgrading neovim
- I've also tried different methods of installation for both
  rust-analyzer and neovim on various versions of each
- Removing everything from my `init.vim` to the point where there was
  only rust-analyzer and the lsp
- Manually change the highlighting rules while the file is open using
  `:hi <group> ...`

  - This had no effect even when using the highlight group that the
    token was supposed to be

Some notes:

- My `init.vim` can be found [here](https://github.com/funnyboy-roks/personal-config/blob/main/nvim/init.vim)
- I am using Arch Linux
- A video of the issue can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4g12Z.jpg)
- When using [this mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29030788), the
  highlight token does not ever change

  - furthermore, when I looked up the highlight group showed in `:hi`, it did
    not have the same style as the one in the document, (i.e. `rustModPath` was blue in
    `:hi`, but showed as purple in the rust file)
  - `:syn` had the same issue as above
  - [`SyntaxAttr`](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) gave the same token with the same problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was really simple, I was just being dumb.

The doc shows how to disable it:
https://neovim.io/doc/user/lsp.html#lsp-semantic-highlight:

> ```lua
> -- Hide semantic highlights for functions
> vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, '@lsp.type.function', {})
> -- Hide all semantic highlights
> for _, group in ipairs(vim.fn.getcompletion("@lsp", "highlight")) do
>  vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, group, {})
> end
> ```

Comment: Maybe could you explain it in your answer.

Comment: Sure! Updated the answer.